# How do you create collision in code.org applab

Tags: javascript, code.org, app-lab

Im trying to create a maze app/game using app lab in code.org

https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/rrV1fA5_uefcGGyrDYnznALkqxdWbjXbmI7nneft2Bg

This is my current project but i dont know how to set the character for the player and I also want to be able to code "if a character touches black then the character reverts back to its original starting position. Any information on how to do this would be great. Thanks